# KMeans Clustering only using specific Csv column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, k-means

Following a tutorial I am learning on how to use Kmeans.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans



X = np.array([[1, 2],
              [5, 8],
              [1.5, 1.8],
              [8, 8],
              [1, 0.6],
              [9, 11]])


kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2 )
kmeans.fit(X)

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

print(centroids)
print(labels)

colors = ["g.","r.","c.","y."]

for i in range(len(X)):
    print("coordinate:",X[i], "label:", labels[i])
    plt.plot(X[i][0], X[i][1], colors[labels[i]], markersize = 10)


plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0],centroids[:, 1], marker = "x", s=150, linewidths = 5, zorder = 10)

plt.show()
```

I want to read a csv file and then instead of the array which is used above, have one of the dataframe columns.

I tried the following but I did't work

```
df=pd.read_csv("Output.csv",encoding='latin1')
X=pd.DataFrame([['Column_1']])
```

I got the following error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Column_1'
```

This is how my output looks when I use `df.head`

```
    x    id  ... Column_name v      Column_1
0  25  0001  ...         NaN             854
1  28  0002  ...         NaN            85,4
2  29  0003  ...         NaN            1524
3  32  NaN   ...         NaN               0
4  85  0004  ...         NaN               0
```

Comment: One reason is that in your dataset in 'Column_1', there might be some junk data that cannot be converted to float.

Comment: @N.Moudgil, the data is good. It is just numbers while some of them might be with decimals

Comment: in your code : X=pd.DataFrame([['Column_1']]) is a mistake I guess.
Did you tried something like X=df[['Column_1']] ?

Comment: @Louis Hulot, I am getting the error saying that ```ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3352,4'```

Comment: I think you are not reading the csv properly (, is the default separator in a csv file).
It is not usual to have it in a string. 
Can you display something like df.head() so we can know what there is in your data ?

Comment: @Louis Hulot, check my updated question

Answer (score 2):

When you run following command as in your question

```
X=pd.DataFrame([['Column_1']])
```

X now holds this:

```
        0
0   Columns_1
```

The error is pretty clear as it is saying unable to convert 'Column_1' to float as `kmeans` uses numbers data

you can simplay select your first column as;

```
X=df[['your_first_col_name']]
```

**Edit**
To handle commas you can use:

```
df['Column_1']=df['Column_1'].str.replace(',','.')
```

One more way to handle data that contains `','` instead of `'.'` for decimals as is the case with European format, is to declare `decimal` argument while reading `csv`
so, if original data is like this:

```
A
1253
1253,5
12578,8
148,45
124589
```

we can read this data as

```
df=pd.read_csv('c2.csv', decimal=',')
```

and output will be

```
0      1253.00
1      1253.50
2     12578.80
3       148.45
4    124589.00
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I tried ```X=df[['your_first_col_name']]``` but I get the error ```ValueError: could not convert string to float: '525,4' ```  . I think this might be because some of the values in that column are decimals

Comment: yes, decimals and there is `,` in between them you should remove those using `.replace()` method. i am only saying decimal as in above error `,` is at very last.

Comment: I have added how the output looks like when i just print the head. Can you please help me on how to implement this into the code

Comment: If I used your updated answer like this ```X=df['Column_1']=df['Column_1'].str.replace(',','.') ```. I get en error saying that ```ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:   ```

Comment: @mandi that's another issue related to K-Means and scaling  you will have to share complete details where error occurs or start another post related to it

Comment: I didn't know that I have just started to learn more about K-Means. This is the complete error ```ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[2.96980e+04 3.95500e+03 1.53520e+04 ... 1.31584e+05 0.00000e+00
 2.53000e+01].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.     ```

Comment: `kmeans.fit(X.values.reshape(1,-1))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206784/discussion-between-m-s-n-and-mandi).

Comment: what should I do with ```kmeans.fit(X.values.reshape(1,-1))  ```. I'm sorry but this laptop  is not letting me go to the discussion chat. I can do so later today when I have access to my own laptop

Comment: the thing is see where the error occurs, then try to reshape the values as it is mentioned the error thrown. you can also do `X=X.values.reshape(1,-1)` and then use this new X for further operations

Comment: I am really sorry for all these questions. I put the code ```X=X.values.reshape(1,-1)  ``` just after ```X=df['Column_1']=df['Column_1'].str.replace(',','.') ``` . Not sure if that is the right order but If I run the code that way I get the following error ```ValueError: n_samples=1 should be >= n_clusters=2    ```

Comment: change `reshape(1,-1) to reshape(-1,1)`

Comment: ```IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1```